# Python Anywhere package install issue

Tags: python, pythonanywhere

So I'm trying to run a program which imports a package with the Python MDSplus module (a Python Package), and it is working great on my computer. In short, it is a standard python package with a good number of submodules, which are initialized by the global load method in the folder.
However, when I run it on PythonAnywhere, the main package I import cannot load the submodules, and my program fails.Is anyone familiar with this type of problem? I believe it is a permissions issue, but nothing looks wrong. Everything in the Library appears to be in the right place, it's just not recognizing the modules.

Comment: I've not used `pythonanywhere`, but looking through its forums and [other similar SO questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pythonanywhere%20importerror?mode=all), (at least this one [ImportError : cannot import name timezone pythonanywhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39238782/importerror-cannot-import-name-timezone-pythonanywhere)), did you ensure you are using a version of python that is compatible with the MDSplus module?

Comment: Also how did you install MDSplus? [Pypi shows it's still at version 1.0](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/MDSplus)

Comment: A. I'm using Python3.6, which is compatible.  B) im using the alpha found here  https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mdsplus-alpha/7.1.77    it works fine on my computer

Comment: great. I noticed you also posted your issue on the forums, hopefully will get better feedback there or from another user here. Sorry I was of no help, good luck!

Comment: Sure, I'd be happy to try and help more if you don't get any further feedback.

Comment: Are you sure you installed it for the correct Python version on PythonAnywhere?  That is, did you use `pip3.6 install --user XXXXX` or install it into the correct virtualenv?